# Setting up Flask with react-starter-kit

Tags: reactjs, flask, graphql, react-starter-kit, flask-graphql

This questions is pretty specific to the react-starter-kit, though, someone else may be able to help here on the internets. I am trying to use the react-starter-kit with a flask application I am developing. I chose this yeoman generator as it had a lot of things I am looking for, though, I don't want to run on a node server. I have a flask app that I would just like to wire up to the react front end. I can't quite figure out how the node routes know which `.js` bundled file to include (and Node routes are a bit confounding to me anyways). Where would be the best place to start here?

I think if I could start with a specific question, to what `.js` file could I have an `index.html` point to? Or how can I find that?

I am tentative to ask this question here, but I hopefully will be directed to the right place.

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flask React</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- styles -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script type="text/js" src="build/assets.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my flask view:

```
@CORE.route('/', methods=['GET'])
  def index():
      return render_template('index.html')
```

Here is the `build/assets.js`

```
module.exports = {"main":{"js":"/main.js?032d72b634c91d2f8756"}};
```

Where the `/main.js?{{string}}` points the that bundled version of the app.

Here is the file directory layout:

```
App
|-app
  |-Core
    |-view.py
  |-Templates
    |-index.html
|-build
  |-assets.js
|-src
```

Comment: So you plan on having an 'index' route in flask that returns a template that links the source JS file?

Comment: @PatrickAllen yeah, at least to start while I am figuring this out. I am playing around right now and going to try and have it point to the `build/assets.js` and see what happens... right track?

Comment: well that didn't work...

Comment: What didn't work? Please include the file directory layout of your application and the HTML that you are using to load the React scripts

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated the most so that it would be a little more clear.

Comment: @cricket_007 let me know if there's more that I should include.

Answer (score 1):

What I have decided to do, and what I would recommend doing, is to use Graphene and Flask-GraphQL alongside the react-starter-kit. Then to get to my data I can just have the node server query to the flask server to get the data from postgres. This will allow me to still to data-y things in python with the flask server and produce a RESTful API if needed, but will allow me to benefit from the awesomeness of GraphQL.

I am still getting everything figured out, and I will come back to repost in the future when I get things working all the way.